# Logstash - File Input - Changes on file don't affect

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm running Logstash with docker on my machine with this command:

```
docker run  -it  -v /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf:/Users/igunel/Desktop/logstash.conf --name myLogstash --network=elastic-network  -e "ssl_certificate_verification=false" logstash:8.8.1
```

The logstash.conf file is like this:

```
input {
 file { 
 path => '/Users/igunel/Desktop/SpringBootELK.log'
 }
}
output {
 file {
 path => '/Users/igunel/Desktop/output.txt'
 codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

When I edit the SpringBootELK.log, there is no affect on logstash. The output.txt file is not being created. What is the wrong point? Why don't changes have any affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mapped your logstash config the wrong way, it should be `localhost:container`, not the opposite.

You also need to create a volume to map your local files in `/Users/igunel/Desktop` to container-local files so that Logstash can read `SpringBootELK.log` and write to `output.txt`.

Run it like this:

```
docker run  -it \ 
  -v /Users/igunel/Desktop/SpringBootELK.log:/var/log/logstash/SpringBootELK.log \
  -v /Users/igunel/Desktop/output.txt:/var/log/logstash/output.txt \
  -v /Users/igunel/Desktop/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf \ 
  --name myLogstash \
  --network=elastic-network \
  -e "ssl_certificate_verification=false" logstash:8.8.1
```

And you also need to modify your `logstash.conf` file as follows:

```
input {
 file { 
 path => '/var/log/logstash/SpringBootELK.log'
 }
}
output {
 file {
 path => '/var/log/logstash/output.txt'
 codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still problem exists. Both of output.txt has no changes. The change on local SpringBootELK.log file affects to the SpringBootELK.log file which is in docker container. But no change on output.txt.

Comment: Please check my answer again, the logstash.conf file was not in the right folder, it should be in `/usr/share/logstash/pipeline` and not `/usr/share/logstash/config`

Comment: Thank You @Val, it's working very well now.

Comment: Awesome, glad it finally worked out!